# APLpy error: 'Colorbar' object has no attribute 'set_axis_label_text'

Tags: python, matplotlib, title, colorbar, aplpy

I'm trying to write a title for a colour bar in `APLpy` but everytime I do I get the following error:

```
AttributeError:'Colorbar' object has no attribute 'set_axis_label_text'
```

The code I'm using is the following:

```
import aplpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
f1 = aplpy.FITSFigure('random.fits', figure=fig)
f1.show_colorscale(stretch='arcsinh',cmap='Greys',interpolation="bicubic")
f1.add_colorbar()
f1.colorbar.set_width(0.3)
f1.colorbar.set_axis_label_text('title')
plt.show()
```

According to read the docs this should work
http://aplpy.readthedocs.org/en/v0.9.9/quick_reference.html

Comment: which version of matplotlib/aplpy/python are you using?

Comment: @MSeifert Matplotlib is 1.5.1, aplpy is 0.9.6 and canopy is 1.6.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please update APLpy to the newest version. I've looked everywhere but I did not even find anything on `0.9.6`. So probably the method was introduced in a later release.

I think setting labels for colorbars was introduced in [`0.9.9`](https://github.com/aplpy/aplpy/blob/v0.9.9/CHANGES.rst#L32) in [pull request #93](https://github.com/aplpy/aplpy/pull/93).

Comment: that didn't appear to fix the problem

Comment: I edited the answer. I think it's because of your outdated ``APLpy`` version. Could you update it and check? Unfortunatly I didn't find 0.9.6 anywhere so I can't be sure if that's the reason.